# WPF properties not working correctly in windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am having an issue with the BorderThickness or BorderBrush property in Windows 8.

In win7, the code below correctly outlines editControl in a 5px thick read outline, however it does not work in windows 8. I am wondering if there is something deprecated or unsupported in windows 8 now? I cannot find any notion of that on the microsoft documentation.

```
editControl.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);
editControl.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
```

Anyone able to help?

Comment: It would help if you could provide more info on what happens beyond "doesn't work" -- does it throw a runtime or compile time exception?  What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: What i mean is the change is not reflected e.g. the border remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround using using [Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx).

```
  private class ErrorHighlightAdorner : Adorner
  {
      public ErrorHighlightAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
          : base(adornedElement)
      {
      }

      protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
      {
          Rect sourceRect = new Rect();
          FrameworkElement fe = AdornedElement as FrameworkElement;
          if (fe != null)
          {
              sourceRect = new Rect(fe.RenderSize);
          }
          else
          {
              sourceRect = new Rect(AdornedElement.DesiredSize);
          }

          Pen renderPen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 2.0);
          drawingContext.DrawRectangle(null, renderPen, sourceRect);
      }
  }
```